# $(a+b+c)/(x+y+z)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2+c^2 &= m, \\ 
x^2+y^2+z^2 &= n, \\
ax+by+cz &= p,
\end{align*}
find $$(a+b+c)/(x+y+z).$$
I can solve for cases when $$mn=p^2$$
E.g.,$$m=16,n=25,p=20$$
But the general case is not factoring or simplifying much.
Thanks.

Comment: What is known, what is unknown ?

Comment: @JJacquelin m,n and p are known

Comment: So, from your comment one can deduce that $a,b,c,x,y,z$ are unknown. Thus they are 6 unknowns but only 3 equations. The result is undetermined, or they are an infinity of solutions - Of course if there is no additional or hidden or implicit condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy's inequality, $$|ax+by+cz|\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ it must be the case that $p^2\le mn$, otherwise there are no solutions (also $m,n>0$).

In that case, let $A=a/\sqrt{m}$, $B=b/\sqrt{m}$, $C=c/\sqrt{m}$, and $X=x/\sqrt{n}$, etc., $P=p/\sqrt{mn}$. Then the equations become $$A^2+B^2+C^2=1=X^2+Y^2+Z^2,\qquad AX+BY+CZ=P$$ So the question is about two unit vectors $(A,B,C)$, $(X,Y,Z)$ whose dot product is known, that is the angle between them is given. Unless some other conditions are given, there are unit vectors $(X,Y,Z)$ such that $X+Y+Z=0$, for example $(1,1,-2)/\sqrt6$. Hence the fraction $\frac{a+b+c}{x+y+z}=\frac{A+B+C}{X+Y+Z}\frac{\sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{n}}$ can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: but I solved it for m=16,n=25 and p=20, without any other constraint

Comment: Because for $p^2=mn$, there are only two possible values of $(a,b,c,x,y,z)$ that work.  For $p^2<mn$, there are infinitely many possible choices.

Comment: Even in that case, take for example $(a,b,c)=(4,0,0)$, $(x,y,z)=(5,0,-5)/\sqrt2$. The fraction becomes $4/0$.